# Spring instantiate util:list with direct value?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring a List can be instantiated like this:

```
<util:list id="myList">
    <value>someValue<value>
    <value>othervalue<value>
</util:list>
```

but how the list can be instantiated with a reference to something via expression language? 
To have an equivalent of following, but to use `util:list`.

```
<bean id="myList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(con.SomeEnum).INSTANCE.getList()}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<util:list id="myList" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <value>#{...}</value> 
</util:list>
```

Comment: That actually creates a list of lists, with the first value of "myList" the value reference there.

Comment: You should reference it as <property name="prop" ref="myList" /> not value="myList"